# Is is there anyway to attach to a process's maps while keeping your file hidden from the maps

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gdb, g++

```
input="$(
sudo gdb -n -q -batch-silent \
  -ex "set logging on" \
  -ex "set logging file /dev/null" \
  -ex "set logging redirect on" \
  -ex "attach $PID" \
  -ex "set \$dlopen = (void*(*)(char*, int)) dlopen" \
  -ex "call \$dlopen(\"/$filename\", 1)" \
  -ex "detach" \
  -ex "quit"
)"
```

basically I want to attach my file $filename into $PID but I dont want $PID to know that $filename is in its maps? How would I do that

Answer (score 0):

> How would I do that

That isn't easy: there are too many ways for a process to discover that `$filename` is in its address space:

Read these files:

```
/proc/$pid/maps
/proc/$pid/task/$tid/maps
```

Call these functions:

```
dl_iterate_phdr
dladdr
```

Read these global variables:

```
_DYNAMIC[]      /* points to _r_debug */
_r_debug.r_map  /* points to linked list of DSOs */
```

There are probably other ways as well. You'll have intecept all of these, or the process may discover your ruse.

Comment: I heard you could spoof the mapping of the process. Do you know how to do that. I do not know anything about programming, took AP Computer Science, got a 5 but don't understand anything. The whole thing is overwhelming. Please spoon-feed me :(.

Comment: @BoxHeadBlueClan What *actual* problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I just want to bypass VAC anti-cheat.

Comment: If by "VAC anti-cheat" you mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valve_Anti-Cheat, good luck! (What makes you think that you "I don't know anything" can easily bypass a system that professionals have been developing for 15 years?)

Comment: Because it's pretty bad just need to paste the right things.